# Call to undefined method DOMElement::appendChid() in php

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, domdocument

Following is the `working` code that is generating this XML -

Working code link - http://codepad.org/aX5HL6Vp

```
    $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
    $dom->xmlStandalone = false;
    $manfiestNode = $dom->createElement('manifest',"");
    $manfiestNodeAttr = $dom->createAttribute('identifier');
    $date = new DateTime();
    $manfiestNodeAttr->value = 'course_'.date_format($date,'U');
    $manfiestNode->appendChild($manfiestNodeAttr);
$manfiestNode->appendChild($dom->createAttribute('xmlns:xsi'))->appendChild($dom->createTextNode("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"));
    $metaData = $dom->createElement('metadata','');
    $manfiestNode->appendChild($metaData);
    $dom->appendChild($manfiestNode);
    var_dump($dom->saveXML());
```

XML generated from the code -

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no" ?>
<manifest identifier="com.scorm.golfsamples.contentpackaging.multioscosinglefile.20043rd"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <metadata>
  </metadata>
</manifest>
```

But I am trying to add child node to `metadata` node and everything went wrong :(

XML to generate -

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no" ?>
<manifest identifier="com.scorm.golfsamples.contentpackaging.multioscosinglefile.20043rd"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <metadata>
    <schema>ADL SCORM</schema>
    <schemaversion>2004 3rd Edition</schemaversion>
  </metadata>
</manifest>
```

Code **NOT** working -

Codepad link - http://codepad.org/XLwp4AbQ

```
    $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
    $dom->xmlStandalone = false;   
    $manfiestNode = $dom->createElement('manifest',"");
    $manfiestNodeAttr = $dom->createAttribute('identifier');
    $date = new DateTime();
    $manfiestNodeAttr->value = 'course_'.date_format($date,'U');
    $manfiestNode->appendChild($manfiestNodeAttr);
$manfiestNode->appendChild($dom->createAttribute('xmlns:xsi'))->appendChild($dom->createTextNode("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"));
    $metaData = $dom->createElement('metadata','');
    $manfiestNode->appendChild($metaData);
    $schema = $dom->createElement('schema','ADL SCORM');
    $schemaVersion = $dom->createElement('schemaversion', '2004 3rd Edition');
    $metaData->appendChid($schema);
    $metaData->appendChid($schemaVersion);
    $dom->appendChild($manfiestNode);
    var_dump($dom->saveXML());
```

**Error** -

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMElement::appendChid()

Let me know what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: bad very bad :( voted to close it :(  `Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist 1`

Comment: Did you tried @number50 answer? Your issue about wrong spelling.

Comment: @Bora yeah thats why I added this comment :(

Answer (score 3):

You have made a spelling mistake, instead of `appendChild` you write `appendChid`.

First correct it, and then check what happens.