# Call to undefined method DOMElement::appendChid()

Tags: php

I generating xml.When i try to add cdata it gives me error

```
$dom = new DomDocument("1.0", "ISO-8859-1");
$root = $dom->appendChild($dom->createElement( "Questions")); 
$sxe = simplexml_import_dom( $dom ); 
$question = $sxe->addchild("Question");
$question->addAttribute('id', $Question_Id);
$question->addAttribute('type', $type);                     
$question->appendChild($sxe->createCDATASection( $Questiontext));//error
$question->addChild('Option_One', $Option_One);
$dom->formatOutput = true; 
$xmlString = $dom->saveXML(); 
print($xmlString);
$dom->save("{$Campaign_Name}.xml");
```

Comment: Try to call $dom->appendChild($sxe->createCDATASection($Questiontext));

Comment: This is the same question as this :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18611202/call-to-undefined-method-domelementappendchid-in-php

Comment: Did you write appendChid as in your question or appendChild as in your description ?

Answer (score 1):

You have made a spelling mistake, instead of `appendChild` you write `appendChid`

Answer (score 0):

```
$question->appendChild(new DOMElement('direction'))->appendChild(new DOMCdataSection('<p>Hello!</p>'));
```

for DOM